# Prove connectedness for these sets

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

Let $(X,T)$ a connected space and $Y\subset X$ a closed connected subset such that $X\setminus Y$ is disconnected with open partition in $A$ and $B$. Prove that $Y\cup A$ and $Y\cup B$ are connected.

**My idea:**
$A$ and $B$ are opens from the subspace $X\setminus Y$ which is open in $(X,T)$ hence $A$ and $B$ actually belong to $T$.
Suppose $A\cup Y\subset C\cup D$ for disjoint open sets $C,D$. Then $C\cup D$ is a disjoint open cover of $Y$ hence WLOG $Y\subset C$. But then
$$S:=(D\cap A)\cup(B\cup C)$$
should be a disjoint open cover of $X$. Proof:
**Disjoint:** $(D\cap A)\cap(B\cup C)=(D\cap A\cap B)\cup(D\cap A\cup C)=\emptyset\cup\emptyset=\emptyset$
**Cover:** let $x\in X$. Since $A,B,Y$ form a partition of $X$ there are three cases.

- $x\in Y\implies x\in C\subset S$
- $x\in B \implies x\in S$
- $x\in A \implies\begin{cases}
  x\in C\implies x\in S\\ x\in D \implies x\in D\cap A \subset S\end{cases}$

So $S\subset X \subset S = X$. Now $X$ is connected and $B\cup C\neq\emptyset$ so necessarily $D\cap A=\emptyset$ thus $A\subset C$ thus $A\cup Y\subset C$ which proves the connectedness of $A\cup Y$. Same goes for $B\cup Y$.

Comment: Now your post became a solution-verification question, so I added the corresponding tag. But according to it https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: *"For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so."* That said, I found no error in your proof.

Comment: Except a minor point: the open sets $C,D\in T$ are not necessarily disjoint. It is their intersections with $A\cup Y$ which are disjoint. (But this doesn't essentially affect your proof.)

Comment: Better look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303014 than https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3025311, and notice that your closedness condition is actually useless.

Comment: Merci Anne. I hope the teacher valued at least partially my answer.